# Play framework file upload no such file exception

Tags: java, scala, ubuntu, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to implement file upload with play framework scala. This code works just fine in development(windows) but fails when deployed(Ubuntu).

```
     def upload = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { request =>
      request.body.file("torrentFile").map { picture =>
      import java.io.File
      val filename = picture.filename
      val contentType = picture.contentType
      println(filename)
      println(contentType)
      picture.ref.moveTo(new File("Files/ppp.rdf"))
      Ok("File uploaded")
    }.getOrElse {
      Redirect(routes.Application.index()).flashing(
        "error" -> "Missing file")
    }
}
```

This is the error I get when I try uploading a file

```
    play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[NoSuchFileException: /tmp/playtemp5801072751187159177/multipartBody5640251320440161134asTemporaryFile -> Files/ppp.rdf]
        at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:289) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
        at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:220) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
        at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:160) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
        at play.core.j.JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.play$core$j$JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter$$super$onError(JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.scala:35) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
        at play.core.j.JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter$$anonfun$onError$2.apply(JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.scala:35) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
        at play.core.j.JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter$$anonfun$onError$2.apply(JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.scala:35) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
        at play.core.j.JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.onError(JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.scala:35) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
        at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:100) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:100) [com.typesafe.play.play-netty-server_2.11-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /tmp/playtemp5801072751187159177/multipartBody5640251320440161134asTemporaryFile -> Files/ppp.rdf
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.move(UnixCopyFile.java:457) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.move(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:262) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1395) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at play.api.libs.Files$TemporaryFile.moveTo(Files.scala:102) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
        at controllers.Upload$$anonfun$upload$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Upload.scala:74) ~[untitled10.untitled10-1.0-sans-externalized.jar:na]
        at controllers.Upload$$anonfun$upload$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Upload.scala:68) ~[untitled10.untitled10-1.0-sans-externalized.jar:na]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
        at controllers.Upload$$anonfun$upload$1.apply(Upload.scala:68) ~[untitled10.untitled10-1.0-sans-externalized.jar:na]
```

The applications creates some files and folders when running and this currently happens so I'm sure its not Linux file permission in the directory.
when I go to `/tmp` directory I do not see the play temp files.
I'm working with play 2.5 in intellij.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, try to give a full path instead of `Files`, like `/var/webapps/your-app/files`.

Run the app as `root` **temporary** (using sudo) and make sure that `Files` (/var/webapps/your-app/files) folder exists on the disk.

If the app worked as `root` it shows that there is something wrong about permissions. Make sure the user which the app is running by, have read/write access to `/tmp` and write access to `Files`.